# How do you change Snipcart's default $localize("actions.continue_shopping") label text?

Tags: javascript, localization, snipcart

The following code snippet, as provided by Snipcart's documentation for v3, does not seem to override their default text label: *Continue shopping*

```
document.addEventListener('snipcart.ready', () => {
    Snipcart.api.session.setLanguage('en', {
        actions: {
            continue_shopping: "Go back to store"
        }
    });
});
```

I have placed the above code segment directly underneath the following...

```
<div hidden id="snipcart" data-api-key="[Testing API Key]"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.6/default/snipcart.js"></script>
```

When I click to activate Snipcart's checkout modal, the default label *Continue shopping* remains (instead of, *Go back to store*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue mentioned has been fixed in [V3.0.10](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/release-notes#v3010). The sample code from the question will work as-is.

---

There was an issue with older releases of Snipcart: if localizations are applied too early with the JS API, they'll get overridden when the localization file is loaded.

To ensure everything loads in order, you can update your code to use the `Snipcart.ready` promise:

```js
document.addEventListener('snipcart.ready', () => {
    Snipcart.ready.then(function() {
      Snipcart.api.session.setLanguage('en', {
        actions: {
            continue_shopping: "Go back to store"
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Jean-Sébastien! Your modified script segment has produced the desired result...  Cheers, mate!